# Meaning of #text in DOM parser

Tags: java, dom, xml-parsing

I'm relatively new to XML parsers, trying to understand some java code using DOM api to parse an XML document.

I need to know what '#text' means in the following code or even what this line of code does: -

```
if(!ChildNode.getNodeName().equals("#text"))
{
//do something
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html), `#text` is the value of the `nodeName` attribute for nodes implementing the `Text` interface.

i.e. if a node in the document is a text node (as opposed to, for example, an element), it's `nodeName` will be `#text`.

The code in question appears to be checking whether the node referenced by `ChildNode` is a text node before performing some action. Presumably, the action is something that can't be performed upon a text node, like querying or adding to its children.